# Parsing xml soap response with curl php to array

Tags: php, curl, soap

I want to be able to somehow wander, array, json...

What I want to get is: <a:Content>This my content</a:Content>

The plain text appears on the screen, but in the html I see the code that I put below in xml.

I have this curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://uat.centiro.com/Universe.Services/TMSBasic/Wcf/c1/i1/TMSBasic/TMSBasic.svc/xml',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://centiro.com/facade/tmsBasic/1/0/servicecontract" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centiro.Facade.TMSBasic.Contract.c1.i1.TMSBasic.BaseTypes.DTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="http://centiro.com/facade/shared/1/0/datacontract">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns3:AuthenticationTicket>bRElCBN2hRXZ1EonTh7T%2bDhGFNdQLMrSwKYbrgKVat%2biKGUDV0V9fT7Ix</ns3:AuthenticationTicket>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:AddAndPrintShipmentRequest>
  <ns1:LabelType>PDF</ns1:LabelType>
  <ns1:Shipment>
    <ns2:Addresses>
      <ns2:Address>
        <ns2:Address1>Rue 45</ns2:Address1>
        <ns2:AddressType>Receiver</ns2:AddressType>
        <ns2:CellPhone>+33620963055</ns2:CellPhone>
        <ns2:City>Paris</ns2:City>
        <ns2:Contact>Test Name</ns2:Contact>
        <ns2:Email>testname@gmail.fr</ns2:Email>
        <ns2:ISOCountry>FR</ns2:ISOCountry>
        <ns2:Name>Test Name</ns2:Name>
        <ns2:Phone>+33620963055</ns2:Phone>
        <ns2:ZipCode>75002</ns2:ZipCode>
      </ns2:Address>
    </ns2:Addresses>
    <ns2:Attributes>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>OriginSub</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value>ES</ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>CRMID</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value>ES1806025</ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>Product</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value>EPAQSCT</ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>Service</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value>CUP</ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>AdditionalService</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value>SIG</ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
      <ns2:Attribute>
        <ns2:Code>Format</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Value></ns2:Value>
      </ns2:Attribute>
    </ns2:Attributes>
    <ns2:ModeOfTransport>ACSS</ns2:ModeOfTransport>
    <ns2:OrderNumber>ORD0001001</ns2:OrderNumber>
    <ns2:Parcels>
      <ns2:Parcel>
        <ns2:Height>0</ns2:Height>
        <ns2:Length>0</ns2:Length>
        <ns2:ParcelIdentifier>PRCID0001001</ns2:ParcelIdentifier>
        <ns2:TypeOfGoods>Goods</ns2:TypeOfGoods>
        <ns2:TypeOfPackage>Small Packet</ns2:TypeOfPackage>
        <ns2:Weight>1.1</ns2:Weight>
        <ns2:Width>0</ns2:Width>
      </ns2:Parcel>
    </ns2:Parcels>
    <ns2:SenderCode>ES17060029</ns2:SenderCode>
    <ns2:ShipDate>2018-08-09T19:12:47</ns2:ShipDate>
    <ns2:ShipmentIdentifier>SHIP0001001</ns2:ShipmentIdentifier>
    <ns2:ShipmentType>OUTB</ns2:ShipmentType>
    <ns2:TermsOfDelivery>DDP</ns2:TermsOfDelivery>
    <ns2:Weight>1.1</ns2:Weight>
  </ns1:Shipment>
</ns1:AddAndPrintShipmentRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
'SOAPAction: http://centiro.com/facade/tmsBasic/1/0/servicecontract/ITMSBasic/AddAndPrintShipment'
 ),
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 print_r($response);
```

And this is the response in browser:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Header>
    <h:ErrorMessages i:nil="true" xmlns:h="http://centiro.com/facade/shared/1/0/datacontract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <h:Success xmlns:h="http://centiro.com/facade/shared/1/0/datacontract">true</h:Success>
 </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <AddAndPrintShipmentResponse xmlns="http://centiro.com/facade/tmsBasic/1/0/servicecontract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ParcelDocuments xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centiro.Facade.TMSBasic.Contract.c1.i1.TMSBasic.BaseTypes.DTO">
            <a:ParcelDocument>
                <a:Content>This my content</a:Content>
            </a:ParcelDocument>
        </ParcelDocuments>
    </AddAndPrintShipmentResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I have tried everything with

- $result = simplexml_load_string(response);
- $result = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

I can't get any way to access <a:Content>This my content</a:Content>

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/

Comment: Thanks, but not working... In the end I have already put this:

$partes = explode("<a:Content>", $response);
$partes = explode("</a:Content>", $partes[1]);
$pdf = $partes[0];
echo $pdf;